# Unable to get property 'setState' of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to add some filtering to an app but my change handler does not appear to have a reference to 'this'? Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
class ShipmentList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            shipments: [],
            searchString: '',
            loading: false
        }
    }

    handleChange(e){
    this.setState( {searchString:e.target.value} )   // <- This is where the error happens  
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch('/shipments-server.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(shipments => this.setState({
            shipments,
            loading: false
        }))

    render() {
    const { shipments, loading, searchString } = this.state
    var shipmentData = shipments
    var filter = this.state.searchString

    if( filter.length > 0 ) {
        shipmentData = shipmentData.filter(s => {
            return s.carrierName.toLowerCase().match( filter.trim().toLowerCase() )
        });
    }


    return (
        <div className="shipment-list">
            <ul className="filters">
                <li><input value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Filter by Carrier" type="text" /></li>
```

My data loads fine from the JSON file but when I type into the input textbox and the handleChange() method is called I see the error 'Unable to get property 'setState' of undefined or null reference'. When I set a breakpoint in the compiled code, I can see that 'this' is undefined within the scope of the handleChange() method but I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Three very helpful answers! Thank you all so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the newer ES6 class syntax you'll lose the autobinding feature that `createClass` provided. This has been a deliberate change because JavaScript classes don't do autobinding either (so the behaviour is consistent), you can read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding

To solve this, you can either go back to the old `createClass` syntax, or manually bind the context to your method in couple of ways:

1. Use `bind()` on the method: `<input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />`
2. Wrap inside an arrow function: `<input onChange={() => this.handleChange()} />`
3. Use the ES7 bind operator (requires proper Babel configuration): `<input onChange={::this.handleChange} />`

A small problem with this is that both `bind()` and the arrow function declaration (and probably the bind operator too, but not 100% sure) would basically create a new method, every time your `render()` function is called. This has some performance implications (although you'll usually don't have to worry about this). If this is a issue however, you can consider assigning the bounded method to a variable upon initialisation and referring to that. Something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  // ...
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Or, if your Babel configuration allows for the Class Properties syntax, you can even skip having to write assignments like these (and having to figure out when you need them), by just directly using arrow functions for everything:

```
class ShipmentList extends Component {

    handleChange = () => {
        // your handleChange code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this`. Try this in your constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        shipments: [],
        searchString: '',
        loading: false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing binding the `handleChange` try it like this:

```
<input value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Filter by Carrier" type="text" />
```

## Edit 1

Just as [@fabian-schultz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6941627/fabian-schultz) pointed out you can also do it in the constructor if you are worry about the hit of performance:

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            shipments: [],
            searchString: '',
            loading: false
        }
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when binding your methods inside a JSX prop it will create a brand new function on every single render, which is bad for performance.

Comment: this one is new for me, great tip!!